# Directory website category - Singular or Plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am creating a directory website having multiple categories and sub-categories.

I am confused about whether I should use category name singular or plural?

Example:

Should I set category name

- **Industry** or **Industries**
- **Food and Beverage** or **Foods and Beverages**
- **Real Estate and Building** or **Real Estates and Buildings**
- **Financial Service** or **Financial Services**
- **Business and Service** or **Business and Services**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely a matter of style and choice which you use

- **Dictionaries** normally use singular nouns
- **Directories** mostly use uncountable and plural nouns (see for example Ebay)

You might be interested in this article about [Yahoo Directory](https://searchengineland.com/yahoo-directory-close-204370).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and article link. I am aware of this situation but it was Yahoo which was dominating this before Google. Everything has a lifecycle and Google too. I am not here saying that I will take over google (never know :P) but the thing is should not seat and drop an idea because some players are already paying their game. BTW, I am trying to make a customized local directory for a small town on the earth.